# adaptive load balancing with gnu parallel

Tags: google-compute-engine, gnu-parallel

Is there some way to run gnu parallel with a dynamically changing list of remote hosts? The dynamism isn't intermittent or irregular -- I'm looking for a way to use the Google compute engine autoscaling feature to smoothly scale up to a max number of hosts and have gnu parallel dispatch jobs as these hosts come alive. I guess I can create a fake job to trigger autoscaling to launch the multiple hosts and have them register themselves to some central host file.. Any ideas how best to manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man parallel`:

```
   --slf filename
            File with sshlogins. The file consists of sshlogins on
            separate lines.
            : 
            If the sshloginfile is changed it will be re-read when a
            job finishes though at most once per second. This makes it
            possible to add and remove hosts while running.
```

Comment: That's awesome! I guess my local installation of gnu parallel is outdated and doesn't have this in the manpages... Let me try this...

Comment: Introduced in 20150122.